# How to get all the row indices when I select datagrid rows using shift key?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid

How can I collect all the row indices that I selected in a spark datagrid using shift key and I want to collect them in an arraycollection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [selectedIndices](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#selectedIndices) property.  It will give a [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html); which is like a Typed Array.  If you really need an ArrayCollection you can write a conversion routine.  If you're using Apache Flex, there is also a [VectorCollection](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/org/apache/flex/collections/VectorCollection.html) class you could use.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourAC : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each (var elem:Object in yourDataGrid.selectedIndices) {
    yourAC.addItem(elem);
}
```